# Painting a car in 3D then generating stencils

Tags: adobe-photoshop, vector, texture

I'm not really sure what software solution would be best, or if one even exists, but I have a car that I want to design the paint job for. It appears that Photoshop can import a 3D model and from there I can go ahead and paint it. What I'd like to be able to do is then convert the layers into stencils so that I can then actually paint my car.

I would prefer to work in a vector-based system and that seems to be more in the realm of Illustrator than Photoshop, but it's been a number of years since I have used either. Are there any programs that get me close? I'm more than fine to do some development on my end to close any holes between software solutions if I have to go through multiple pieces of software so long as I can automate the process of generating stencils after I complete the artwork.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way might be to export orthographic renderings from useful angles to serve as templates in Illustrator.  Analogous to something like : http://sean-mccloud777.deviantart.com/art/Volkswagen-Golf-5-409432588

If you would rather work on a 3D object more directly perhaps you can import your textured car model into a 3d modelling package and trace your vector art with actual geometry on the cars surface.  Then export the flattened but not distorted meshes to illustrator for editing and printing.

something like this https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28678/flatten-mesh-with-no-distortion